# Evaluate $\int_{\Bbb{R}^2} e^{-2x^2 -2 y^2 - 2xy} \, {\rm d}(x,y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to evaluate a double integral with $f(x,y) = e ^{-2x^{2} - 2y^{2} - 2xy }$ with bounds of $x$ and $y$  going from $-\infty$ to $+ \infty$  .

I have no idea on how to start. If anybody can help me, I would be happy. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: $2x^2+2y^2+2xy=\frac32(x+y)^2+\frac12(x-y)^2$. Are you sure the sign of the exponent is right?

Comment: It was a typo . i have edited question

Comment: As written, your integral diverges.

Comment: @user_of_math but it has a finite answer in textbook

Comment: @HenningMakholm I have edited question . Sorry for inconvenience

Comment: @JessicaGtb Either your book/homework has a grievous typo in it or you have done a very poor job of proof-reading your transcription of the problem to this site. Since $e^{2x^2+2y^2+2xy} \geq 1$ for all $x$ and $y$, the integral diverges (as user_of_math has pointed out).

Comment: Okay. The hint is still good. Do you know how to integrate $\iint e^{-x^2-y^2} \,dxdy$ by going to polar coordinates?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Can you please elaborate more ? i know about polar coordinates but what about limits .

Comment: @JessicaGtb Since the x,y cover the entire plane, the limits in polar are $r=[0,\infty]$, $\theta=[0,2\pi]$. Don't forget the jacobian when you substitute for $dx dy$.

Comment: @JessicaGtb: First study the integration of $\iint e^{-x^2-y^2}\,dxdy$, presented, for example, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral). Then your integral is but a change of variables away.

Comment: @HenningMakholm i have to substitute x+y = u and x-y =v to solve asper ur hint

Comment: @JessicaGtb: Yes, followed by some scaling. Or just do it in one step with $u=\sqrt{3/2}(x+y)$ and $v=\sqrt{1/2}(x-y)$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Where is need of polar coordinate as suggested by user of math .

Comment: @JessicaGtb: Polar coordinates are the standard way to evaluate $\iint e^{-u^2-v^2}\,dudv$ which you'll now end up with. It is even likely that this is done explicitly somewhere in your textbook, so you just need to appeal to that known result rather than reproducing the argument.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ok Thanks

Comment: Sorry, my answer had a typo in the first $J$ matrix, I corrected it.

Comment: @HenningMakholm In your very first comment. How did you find out such representation . I mean how did 3/2 and 1/2 factors came out. Thanks

Comment: @TaylorTed: It's a year ago, by I think I must just have noticed that the exponent was a linear combination of $x^2+y^2$ and $xy$, and I know that $(x+y)^2$ and $(x-y)^2$ are two independent combinations of these terms -- so expressing the former in terms of the latter is just a matter of solving a simple 2-variable system of equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Henning Makholm pointed out, the problem can be rewritten as 
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left(-\frac{3}{2}(x+y)^2-\frac{1}{2}(x-y)^2\right)\,\mathrm dx\mathrm dy.
$$
With the change of coordinates
$$\binom{a}{b}=\pmatrix{1&1\\1&-1}\binom{x}{y}=J\binom{x}{y}$$
we obtain
$$I=\frac{1}{|\det(J)|}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left(-\frac{3}{2}a^2-\frac{1}{2}b^2\right)\,\mathrm da\mathrm db.$$
With the change of coordinates 
$$\binom{c}{d}=\pmatrix{\sqrt{3/2}&0\\0&\sqrt{1/2}}\binom{a}{b}=K\binom{a}{b}$$
we obtain 
$$I=\frac{1}{|\det(K)|}\frac{1}{|\det(J)|}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left(-a^2-b^2\right)\,\mathrm da\mathrm db,$$ that is, $$I
=\frac{1}{|\det(K)|}\frac{1}{|\det(J)|}\pi=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}.$$